# C++ IDE for Linux with smart reference searching

Tags: c++, linux, ide

Is there an IDE supporting C++ with REALLY smart searching of references? By 'reference' I mean usage of a class (or its member), variable, function in the whole Project or Workspace.

There's lots of IDE providing it. Some of them seem just to search for the text with same name giving lots of stuff, others are smarter and check the context (like class boundaries, namespace) but aren't accurate enough.

The best I've tried so far was Visual SlickEdit, but still there's more to wish.

```
class C1
{
    int foo;
};
class C2
{
    int foo;
};
```

For example in this situation when searching for `C1::foo` references I  DON'T  want `C2::foo` to be shown too.

So, is there an IDE that would be so smart?

**Edit2**

10x everybody for the answers so far.

I tried **Eclipse**, reference searching seems relatively good, but it takes it 20 minutes to index medium size project and 4 times of 5 it runs out of memory and crashes. I tried increasing it and some other advice and it got a little better, but still quite slow and annoying with these crashes.

I tried **KDevelop3**, but the feature mentioned in this question is not very advanced - seems to be just very advanced `grep` based text searching.

**Edit4**

**KDevelop4** - I tried to make it work, but latest beta it's quite unusable for custom makefile projects, I was unable to do anything with it.

**Edit5**
I was surprised, but **QT Creator** did really well in my tests. It doesn't seem to create some tag/index files, but somehow manages to show very precisely the usage of variable/functions/classes. Unfortunately it seems to not work very correctly with templates, when following definitions of functions.

None of the mentioned IDEs could compete Visual SlickEdit in working with references, virtual functions, etc. QT Creator was the closest though, so I will choose it as an answer to my question.

Comment: I use SlickEdit (14.0.1.2) and that seems to work for me.  I have to do a "Find in Files" in project-files if I do want all references to foo.  For virtual functions, it asks whether you want a references to all or just from the class you selected.

Comment: @stefaanv I use GoToRefference from the right-click menu over some item. Isn't "Find in Files" just text search with different options? I did't see any content options there.

Comment: Yep, "Go To Reference" only shows references to C1::foo. "Find in Files" searches text because I see no other way to show references because as far as SlickEdit is concerned, the only resemblence between C1::foo and C2::foo is textual.

Comment: Ok, what I need is exactly to not mix C1::foo and C2::foo, which SlickEdit normally does, but not always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Qt-Creator can help you. There few new features added in new preview 2.0.

Comment: 2.0 is alpha, I'm looking for something more stable, but 1.3.1 did surprisingly well! 10x

Comment: I suggest you to discuss your requirement in official forum or post it in issue Q (at http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator) so it can be included in 2.0 final release.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you could use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) , mainly i think that it will be able to do what you want, or nearly enough. Also [here'](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_search.htm)s a brief description of it's search options.

Comment: 10x, I'm trying it. If I win OutOfMemory battle, it might do the job.

Answer (score 2):

No and I don't think we will ever see implementations that are as good as those in C# or Java editors for two reasons:

1) the preprocessor:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define FOO(x) C1(x).foo
#else
#define FOO(x) C2(x).foo
#endif
```

2) templates:

```
template<class C> void Method(C const& c) {
    printf("%d", c.foo);
}
```

In both cases it is hard to determine which class is actually referenced.

Comment: I think we will see it eventually. As tools like gccxml and concepts like continuous compilation become more mainstream it will become easier for editor authors to integrate "proper" context correct searches.

Having said that I don't think any such editor / process does things "right" on linux yet.

Comment: I think I read on the Visual Studio Developer blog about their implementation and why it is so difficult. If I recall correctly, they already use the compiler to populate their index of symbols but this is not enough because the parsing has to be very fault tolerant. At most times during editing, your code is not well-formed C++. This holds for all languages though.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever try Netbeans. Close competitor of Eclipse it has all its feature like web development, mobile application ide, plugins to almost allow anything to do. All this with lower CPU and memory footprint. And it does resolve the name correctly.

Comment: I've tried it once and didn't like it, but now it seems better somehow. And it does show the usage correctly. 10q, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I feel that people are usually repulsive of the Swing theme at the first look if Netbeans itself. If you change to your native theme then it would look better.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/) myself, but I get the impression that it does some serious parsing of the source code and is able to access source code information though the editor . It has at least some advanced [code assistant functionality](http://zwabel.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/really-rapid-c-development-with-kdevelop4/).

Comment: Yes, I get that. Since I do not program in C++ and have not used KDevelop myself, I am afraid of overselling it. My impression of the tool by having read blog posts about etc over time is that it is very good and above average on this. But I don't know. Hence a "check it out" answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try KDevelop 4, not the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at CodeBlocks [http://www.codeblocks.org/]. I just started using it, but not tested for your requirement. So I am not claiming 10X now. But you can give it a try. Its open source and good one.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it before, but it seems to do just text searching when looking for occurrences of some item, I'm looking for something with deeper code understanding. Except this it seems really nice.