# View Call Hierarchy for operator()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ide

In my unmanaged C++ (VS2010) project, the "View Call Hierarchy" command is not available for operators such as `operator()`, but it works for other functions.

How can I display the call hierarchy of an operator?

Comment: [Similar and might be of help to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516308/caller-graph-for-overloaded-operators-in-visual-studio-2005)